# IIRF ProxyPass ignored

Tags: iirf

I'm using IIRF, IIS 6.0, W2k3.

I'm trying to use ProxyPass, as follows:

```
RewriteLog  c:\temp\iirfLog.log
RewriteLogLevel 3
RewriteFilterPriority HIGH
ProxyPass ^/foo/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [I]
```

but it never works. The IIRF log shows:

```
Wed Jun 30 13:19:54 -  6120 - ReadConfig: setting LogLevel to 3
Wed Jun 30 13:19:54 -  6120 - ReadConfig: line 13: RewriteFilterPriority HIGH
Wed Jun 30 13:19:54 -  6120 - ReadConfig: Filter Priority is now: HIGH (0x80000)
Wed Jun 30 13:19:54 -  6120 - ReadConfig: WARNING: line 14: Ignoring line: 'ProxyPass'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. Turns out we were running a very old version of IIRF. I updated to the latest version, and ProxyPass works now.